# How to check if libpcap installed in Alphine docker container

Tags: linux, docker, libpcap

I installed libpcap in my container using below docker file using docker file below. How do I make sure it was installed and working as expected?

I tried below with the hope to see libpcap

```
D:\work >docker exec -u 0 -it containerId sh

/app # cd /etc/apk

/etc/apk # cat repositories

http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main

http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community

/etc/apk #
```

Below is my docker file

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine AS build

# Install packages
RUN apk update
RUN apk -U --no-cache add libpcap
```

Running the apk info command has below output

WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.adfa7ceb.tar.gz: No such file or directory

WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.efaa1f73.tar.gz: No such file or directory

musl

busybox

alpine-baselayout

alpine-keys

libressl2.7-libcrypto

libressl2.7-libssl

libressl2.7-libtls

ssl_client

zlib

apk-tools

scanelf

musl-utils

libc-utils

ca-certificates

krb5-conf

libcom_err

keyutils-libs

libverto

krb5-libs

libgcc

libintl

libcrypto1.0

libssl1.0

libstdc++

userspace-rcu

lttng-ust

tzdata

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether python package is installed or not in Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27520619/how-to-check-whether-python-package-is-installed-or-not-in-docker)

Answer (score 3):

Run `docker exec` command and try this

```
$ apk info
```

This will list all the installed packages in alpine.

I can see `libcap` in the output.

If you still can't see the package. Make sure you have run `apk update` before installing `libcap`

Comment: Humm...what's wrong I don't see libpcap in the list of my container.

Comment: I used the exact docker image which you trying `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine` and I can see libcap in it.

Comment: Try `docker run -itd mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-alpine sh` and then do `doxker exec -it containerid sh` and run `apk add libcap` and check if it shows libcap package.

Comment: I updated my answer please check apk update might be missing in your case.

Comment: I see libpcap in the list your commands are run, but not using my docker file (I posted my docker file)

Comment: Add `RUN app update` in your dockerfile and try to build and run the image

Comment: You mean RUN apk update? I did, after that libpcap wasn't displayed with apk info command

Comment: Yes, I did put apk update before add after which built the container still I don't see libpcap in the apk info list.

Comment: I suspect that `--no-cache` option in apk add command might causing it to not get it listed in apk info command. Can you try to remove that no-cache option and try again.

Comment: Moving RUN command to the end of docker file (before endpoint) worked.

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you, then please upvote and accept my answer. :)